# Coq: Rewriting between two equivalent setoids

Tags: coq

I have two setoids and bisimilar:

Definition of [lang_iff](https://github.com/awalterschulze/regex-reexamined-coq/tree/edafc1c98311eeda8ec7d30237b14c2eeddfc1ce/src/Brzozowski/Language.v#L25):

```
Definition lang := str -> Prop.
Definition lang_iff (s1 s2: lang): Prop :=
  forall (s: str),
  s \in s1 <-> s \in s2.
```

The setoid [lang_setoid](https://github.com/awalterschulze/regex-reexamined-coq/tree/edafc1c98311eeda8ec7d30237b14c2eeddfc1ce/src/Brzozowski/Setoid.v):

```
Add Parametric Relation: lang lang_iff
  reflexivity proved by lang_iff_refl
  symmetry proved by lang_iff_sym
  transitivity proved by lang_iff_trans as lang_setoid.
```

Definition of [bisimilar](https://github.com/awalterschulze/regex-reexamined-coq/tree/edafc1c98311eeda8ec7d30237b14c2eeddfc1ce/src/Coinduction/Bisimilar.v#L8):

```
CoInductive bisimilar : lang -> lang -> Prop :=
  | bisim : forall (P Q: lang),
    ...
    -> bisimilar P Q.
```

The [bisimilar_setoid](https://github.com/awalterschulze/regex-reexamined-coq/tree/edafc1c98311eeda8ec7d30237b14c2eeddfc1ce/src/Coinduction/Setoid.v):

```
Add Parametric Relation: lang bisimilar
  reflexivity proved by bisimilar_refl
  symmetry proved by bisimilar_sym
  transitivity proved by bisimilar_trans as bisimilar_setoid.
```

These are [proven to be equivalent](https://github.com/awalterschulze/regex-reexamined-coq/tree/edafc1c98311eeda8ec7d30237b14c2eeddfc1ce/src/Coinduction/Bisimilar.v#L82):

```
Theorem bisimilar_is_equivalence:
  forall (P Q: lang),
  bisimilar P Q <-> lang_iff P Q.
```

I can manually rewrite between them with some acrobatics, but was wondering if there is a way to help Coq to see that it can rewrite between two setoids and make the following possible without `Fail`:

```
Example example_rewriting_using_lang_iff_in_bisimilar:
  forall (P Q: lang)
  (pq: lang_iff P Q),
  bismilar Q P.
Proof.
intros.
Fail rewrite pq.
Fail reflexivity.
Abort.
```

The reason for this question is that it is useful to take some steps with coinduction in bisimilar and then resolve an equivalence with lang_iff.

A second part of this question is whether we need to preprove all the morphisms from lang_iff in bimisilar or if there is some command to reuse them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register `bisimilar` as a morphism for `lang_iff`:

```
Add Parametric Morphism : bisimilar
  with signature lang_iff ==> lang_iff ==> iff as bisimilar_lang_morphism.
Proof.
  intros ?? H ?? H'.
  apply  bisimilar_is_equivalence in H, H'.
  split; intro H0.
  now rewrite <- H, H0.
  now rewrite H, H'.
Qed.
```

And now rewriting works in your proof script:

```
Example example_rewriting_using_lang_iff_in_bisimilar:
  forall (P Q: lang)
  (pq: lang_iff P Q),
  bisimilar Q P.
Proof.
  intros.
  rewrite pq.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works really well :)
https://github.com/awalterschulze/regex-reexamined-coq/pull/177